# Reuse case statement in akka messages

Tags: akka

I'm working with scala and akka and I need to optimize some code

```
case message @ Message1(e) =>
  actor ! message

case message @ Message2 =>
  actor ! message
```

as you can see here I'm getting two different messages and calling the same code. Any Idea of how to reuse the same case statement?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
case m @ (Message1(_) | Message2) => actor ! m
```